# concentration constraint for knapsack problem

Tags: linear-programming

I do have a question related to a 0-1 knapsack problem:

I formulated a model with quite a lot of constraints and an objective function on maximizing “balance”. I solved the problem using one of the available commercial solvers (lindo systems). However, would like to put in a couple of extra constraints like;

“the item with the highest balance cannot account for more than 1% of the total balance” (of the solution)

“the item with the 2nd highest balance cannot account for more than 0.5% of the total balance”

Can anyone help me with a solution for such a problem? I have an engineering background, but my math skills are a rusty, so pointers in the right direction would be helpful already.

Comment: I would suggest the PuLP python module. https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I formulated a model with quite a lot of constraints

A knapsack problem has one constraint. If you have many constraints, I would not call it a knapsack problem.

> “the item with the highest balance cannot account for more than 1% of
>   the total balance”

\begin{align} 
    & B = \sum_i b_i\\
    & 0 \le b_i \le 0.01 \cdot B 
\end{align}

where $b_i$ is a variable indicating the balance of item $i$.

> “the item with the 2nd highest balance cannot account for more than
>   0.5% of the total balance”

This is not so trivial. Here is one way with additional binary variables:

\begin{align}
    & b_i \le 0.005 \cdot B + \delta_i \cdot U\\
    & \sum_i  \delta_i = 1\\
    & b_i \in [0,U]\\ 
    & \delta_i \in \{0,1\}
\end{align}

i.e. with one exception all $b_i$ should be less than 0.5% of $B$.

Comment: If $b_i$ are the variables, shouldn't it be $B=\sum_i b_i W_i$ where $W_i$ are the weights ? So that $B$ equals the total balance of the selected items. Or perhaps I misunderstood the interpretation of the $b_i$ variables.

Comment: I just meant: $b_i$ is the "balance" of item $i$ (assumed to be variable). If you want you can interpret $b_i=w_i x_i$.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen: brilliant! Very elegant solution, thank you